# Angular Material - Data table with multiple sort

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-datatables

I have a requirement for a datatable to be sorted by one column, then by second column. Is there something in Angular Material that supports that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of Angular Material there isn't an option for this.

The current version can only look for one `active` class within the table headers.

Are you looking for something like the following?

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MultipleSorting/Angular/Light/

Comment: Something more than this. At any given time, you are sorting on just one column, although all columns are sortable. I need to be able to story by one column, keep that sort active, and then sort by second column. For instance, in the link you mentioned above, I need to be able to sory by State, keep that sort active, then sort by City. Is there anything that supports that functionality?

Comment: Material UI will not do this, as mentioned above. But if you follow this link I posted, this will do what you need. You need to hold down the shift button when selecting the second column.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2020 there is a community addon with MIT-license available that can do multi-sort with `mat-table`, in a similar way as the DevExpress component mentioned here in the answer.

https://github.com/Maxl94/ngx-multi-sort-table

Answer (score 0):

There is no a built-in function for multiple sort but you can create your own custom sort function and overwrite the default one.

Check the example code below

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  ngOnInit() {
    // override the default sortData with our custom sort function
    this.dataSource.sortData = this.customSortData('secondKey');
  }
  // Init dataSource sort after the view init
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  // custom sort function
  customSortData(secondKey: string) {
    let sortFunction = (items: Dessert[], sort: MatSort): Dessert[] => {
      if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
        return items;
      }
      return sortSensorDataByTwoKeys(
        items,
        sort.active,
        secondKey,
        sort.direction
      );
    };
    return sortFunction;
  }
}
// Compare logic
function sortSensorDataByTwoKeys(
  data: any[],
  firstKey: string,
  secondKey: string,
  orderBy: 'asc' | 'desc' = 'asc'
) {
  return data.sort((item1, item2) => {
    if (item1[firstKey] === item2[firstKey]) {
      let valukeKeyresult =
        parseInt(item1[secondKey]) - parseInt(item2[secondKey]);
      if (orderBy === 'desc') {
        valukeKeyresult =
          parseInt(item2[secondKey]) - parseInt(item1[secondKey]);
      }
      return valukeKeyresult;
    }
    let firstKeyResult = parseInt(item1[firstKey]) - parseInt(item2[firstKey]);
    if (orderBy === 'desc') {
      firstKeyResult = parseInt(item2[firstKey]) - parseInt(item1[firstKey]);
    }
    return firstKeyResult;
  });
}
```

If you want to dynamically change the second key, then you'll need to find a way to achieve it.

The important thing is, with this concept, you could sort the data Source by two key values or even other operations.